# Regex to filter webpages names that contains text that you want exclude

Tags: regex

I need to filter webpages names when I using DownThemAll! (a firefox extension)

Some parts of names are structured like this:

```
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=156345
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=458935
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=458935&start=30
/forum/iewtopic.php?t=458935&view=newest
```

I try to write a regex to get only webpages with names like this

```
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=156345
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=458935
```

In other words

```
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=NUMBERS
/forum/viewtopic.php?t=NUMBERS
```

and exclude all webpages that contains anything after that `t=NUMBERS`

I try so but doesn't work

```
^(?!.*start=)|^(?!.*&view=).*viewtopic\.php.*$
```

Sorry, I'm a newbie for regex

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple regex for the searching of lines that end with
`?t=number` :

```
^/forum/viewtopic.php\?t=\d+$
```

Of special note is that the `?` character needs to be escaped.
`\d` stands for a digit.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't select rows when you insert this regex, take a look here, https://i.imgur.com/W28gEm7.png - I don't understand why

Comment: @JackRock `^` matches against the beginning of the subject - since the strings in your image appear to be full URLs rather than just the path portion depicted in your question, remove the `^` to just perform matching on the end of the string. It would also be a good practice to escape the period in `.php`, but it shouldn't really make a functional difference here.

Comment: @bosco no, nothing change also if I remove `^` or if I escape period - I take a look about syntax of regex in Downloadthemall, maybe is limited ? Look here https://i.imgur.com/v3sMp8Q.png

Comment: In that case, just use `^.*\?t=\d+$`, if you don't care what's before the `?`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried, but don't match. I don't understand if downloadthemall support this kind of regex. Have you perhaps tested?

Comment: I know regex, but apparently downloadthemall does not support it well. Strange, as this regex string is rather elementary.